# Filtering By Date Given Google Firestore Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, filtering, querying

Currently, I am uploading information to Google Firestore and will be uploading the information with a date that the user gives. So for instance, before the user uploads, they select a date through `UIDatePicker()`. Which outputs a date in the format as: `Jan 19, 2018`.

Now when the user uploads the document, a field is in the database set to `date`, which will populate `Jan 19, 2018`.

My question is how can I effectively query a list of all the uploads in order by date, starting from the most recent date at the top, and the latest date at the bottom.

My final objective is to create a collection view which will just have the list of all the dates, starting at the most recent.

I cannot do it based on when the user uploads, as the user can upload information that is for a previous day. A user may also upload something to the database for the same day, in which case the date will come twice in a row.

What would be the most effective way?

Is there a query in Firestore which I could do? Or will I need to get all the document dates, and sort them myself within the application?

Any guidance would be great!

Thank you,

Comment: As of now, Firestore has `Timestamps`, not `Date`. Is that what your document has? Also, UIDatePicker returns a `Date`, not a `String` in the format you said.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can't apply query using date i.e. Jan 19, 2018. Only the thing is useful for your case is to store timestamp in **FireStore**. You can easily convert date into timestamp by using following code:

```
extension UIDate {
      var millisecondsSince1970:Int {
          return Int((self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0).rounded())
      }
}

Date().millisecondsSince1970 // 1476889390939
```

Then you can apply FireStore following query to get records on the basis of timestamp

```
databaseRef.order(by: "timeStamp", descending: true)
```

Comment: Much simpler, you can save the `Date` to Firestore with `Timestamp(date: startDate)`. This requires `import FirebaseFirestore`.